# Fragment going over ActionBar in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am using viewpager to show different fragments but in this one of fragment replaces the actionbar. Till now I have found that it is because of `edittext` which I am using for searching items. When I remove `edittext` from this it works fine.

The main activity layout is a CoordinatorLayout, containing the typical AppBarLayout and then a ViewPager and it is filling whole screen.

fragment_gst_rates.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:padding="5dp"
       tools:context="com.kamalarora.mygst.FragmentGstRates">

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

              <EditText
                  android:id="@+id/searchBox"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:hint="Search items . . ."
                  android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                  android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                  android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"/>

          </LinearLayout>

          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:background="@color/lightGrey">
              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="Products"
                  android:textSize="18dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                  android:padding="5dp"/>
              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="GST Rate"
                  android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                  android:textSize="18dp"
                  android:gravity="right"
                  android:padding="3dp"/>

          </LinearLayout>


          <ListView
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:id="@+id/listView">
          </ListView>

      </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.kamalarora.mygst.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/appbar_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="104dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:itemBackground="@color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/mediumgrey"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/mediumgrey"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom" />

    <!--<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" /> -->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: pls post your main activity xml code.

Answer (score 0):

do you tried with the linear layout at the root there try change with android:layout_height="wrap_content" .